# Pricing Tables admin page capability

Tags: capabilities, add-submenu-page

I'm creating a plugin that will allow to create Pricing Tables in a fast and easy way. But, I'm not sure what rule to use for capability. What would you use? Right now I'm using `edit_pages`:

```
add_submenu_page( 'tools.php', 'SMK Pricing Tables', 'SMK Pricing Tables', 'edit_pages', 'smk_pricing_tables', 'admin_page' );
```

Should I use `edit_theme_options` ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no right answer to this.

You need to use the capability or capabilities that allow the users ***you want*** to have access to have access and prevent the users ***you don't want*** to have access from having access.

I would tend to create a capability and/or role in this kind of circumstance, but again, it depends on what ***you*** need.

It is pretty easy to create a role with [`add_role`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role). Also see [`add_cap`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_cap). A [role management plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=Role) can help you work out what you need and what you don't.